# JMS TopicBrowser Import

Tags: java, import, jms, jms-topic

I'm trying to use TopicBrowser (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12023/oracle/jms/TopicBrowser.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/jm_pblsh.htm#CHDEAAJI)) to view messages for a durable subscriber but I cannot find the proper way to import it in my code. I'm new to Java so I may be missing something in the documentation.

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct import statement was

```
import oracle.jms.TopicBrowser;
```

My issue was that I needed to add aqapi.jar to the class path.